# Can we not delete milstones in an entitlement process in salesforce?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I have a 5 milestones in my entitlement process. Now I want to change the order of one of those and need to delete 1 milestone. Unfortunately it looks to me that salesforce doesn't provide delete option for the milestone ?

How to achieve above requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the Entitlement Process and then delete 1 milestone and then use this new Entitlement Process to an Entitlement Record.

If records already exist on Entitlement Process or Milestones then that cannot be deleted.

Comment: yes, I have, please ask a separate question I will answer that. and accept this if it solves your current queston

Comment: sure ! Could you please answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184539/how-to-track-sla-ola-for-different-processes-in-salesforce ?

Comment: Santanu - Although I clone the whole entitlement process, I dont see option to remove the milestones, which I dont now ?

Comment: after cloning, go the milestone list, where you can add, edit or delete milestones

Comment: right, thanks ! Could you please guide on other question ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the setting by going into the path - 
**Build -> Customize -> Entitlement Management -> Entitlement Settings**

[image]

This will give option to make a clone of an existing Entitlement Process. Once you make a clone you need to deactivate the old Entitlement process and make a change in the clone Entitlement Processes.

**Note:** You need to make sure to activate latest version of the Entitlement Processes.

When You're deleting the InActive Entitlement Processes, you need to remove the linkage of the Cases with Entitlement Processes, then you can easily delete entitlement processes. This works fine for me.