# How we can track time of Violated Milestones ?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I've taken a reference from link : [How to track SLA/OLA for different processes in Salesforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184539/how-to-track-sla-ola-for-different-processes-in-salesforce/184604?noredirect=1#comment278239_184604) and now wanted to ask about violated scenarios.

I've the following questions in my mind:

1. Can two milestones be execute at the same time if the milestones are independents of each other ?
2. Can we not execute milestone-2 if milestone-1 fails or violated ? Do we need to wait for the someone to initiate milestone-1 and then only completion of milestone-1, milestone-2 can be executed ?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not complete the milestone automatically.

You need to run a code to complete the milestone. It is possible multiple milestones are run simultaneously if you don't complete other ones.

Code to complete milestone is as follows:

```
public class MilestoneUtils 
{
    public static void completeMilestone(List<Id> caseIds, DateTime complDate) 
    {

        List<CaseMilestone> cmsToUpdate = [select Id, completionDate
                                            from CaseMilestone cm
                                            where caseId in :caseIds and IsCompleted =False
                                            and completionDate = null limit 1];
            if (cmsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false)
            {
                for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate)
                {
                    cm.completionDate = complDate;
                }
            update cmsToUpdate;
            }
    }
}
```

Secondly milestones can be initiated based on certain values on Case record. Let's say you have written a logic, if case status is in-progress and case type is "Accounting" then new milestones gets created.

> So, during creation, system will not look for any previous milestones running or not.

Refer [Milestone Recurrence Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestone_sequential_recurrence.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: Is that my answer serves for you?