# Milestone-1 taking time of Milestone-2 and hence Milestone-2 has less time than actual to execute

Tags: apex, casemilestone, entitlements

I have a two Milestones in my Entitlement Process, Target time for `Milestones-1` is 7 min and `Milestones-2` is 5 min.

[image]

But what I am seeing that, when `Milestones-1` started and say its completed in 4 min then `Milestones-2` is triggering, but the target time is being shown by the system is 2 min, ideally it should be a 5 min. But `Milestones-1` time 4 min is getting subtracted from the `Milestones-2` target time which is bad. For that reason I am getting less time than anticipated. How to solve this issue ?  **When Milestone-2 is completed, then its getting removed from the entiltment related list why ?**

[image]

======================================================================

**Edit-1:**

New behavior is seen in the below. Although, Milestone is completing successfully, still Milestone-2 using the same start date why ?

[image]

Comment: how did you define the milestone recurring type?

Comment: Are you Changing the case status to "Working" at some point before you really want to start the countdown for milestone 2? As I read it you have 7 minutes to pick up the case and once the status is "Working" you have 5 minutes to change the status to something else. Then again, I have not really played with Milestones just giving a completely outside take on it.

Comment: Milestone and Entitlement processes are very tricky and lot needs to be improved. Not sure why Milestone-1 spent time is showing in Milestone-2 ? This is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started 2 milestones without completing the first one, that's why `Milestone-2` is taking the same `target end time` of the first one.

I think in the milestone's configuration, whenever case status changes you are creating the new milestone until case status is not completed.

> Salesforce doesn't automatically close the previous milestone, before creating the new one.
>
> You need to explicitly complete the previous milestone on the after update trigger of Case object.

Refer your previous question [How we can track time of Violated Milestones ?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184804/how-we-can-track-time-of-violated-milestones) where I have given the code to complete milestone.

When you complete the previous one and start the new one then 2 records will be visible in the related list (which is currently showing one).

**Update**

You need to change recurrence type as **Independent**

Comment: whats  your milestones recurring type defined?

Comment: Also, try to look back your previous question, think thoroughly and then post your questions. It will then help you

Comment: You need to change recurrence type as **Independent**

Comment: Very first time I have written an answer to create Independent milestone type, you didn't read that properly. And you are posting same types of questions

Comment: yes, it is, create that way

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_setting_milestones.htm&type=0

Comment: This works fine!