# How to achive recurring processes SLA using Entitlement Process and Milestone?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I have a huge Process Map flow. In this process map assume I have 25 processes. Now I have to calculate the SLA between those steps, also there could be status to distinguished Status etc, but may not be available not sure though.

1) setp-2 to step 20  ==> Assume SLA is 7 business day

2) step-5 to step-17  ==> Assume SLA is 4 business day

3) step-10 to step-15 ==> Assume SLA is 1 business day

Now, what I did, I created  a Milestone-1, where based on some criteria I am initiating the Milestone-1, but say step-5 arrives, with some status or any identifier, then I have to execute Milestone-2, at the same time Milestone-1 will be active ? Milestone-1 Need to pause ? What if we kept open ? Will both Milestone-1 and Milestone-2 clock/timer will run ?  Assume there could be approval and rejection steps between step-5 to 17, so again data submit etc and start from step-5 to 17. Milestone-3, I have to execute again if step-10 comes and criteria matches.

Here can I make the use of OOTB functionality to satisfy all the above requirements? Can we calculate SLA between each 3 types of steps ?

Comment: I have already given answer to your previous question, did you follow that properly, you are asking same types of questions repeatedly. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184539/how-to-track-sla-ola-for-different-processes-in-salesforce/184604#184604

Comment: Its not exactly the same requirement sir.  its little different too